# converting element by using AS operator

Tags: actionscript-3

So im creating something that now is finished and i want not to create every time elements, but to Pool them (ObjectPooling)

The problem comes that my object from the pool doesnt have the variable from the class it mimics, or at least i understand it that way, cause it doesnt do what it should.

Can someone tell me does this

```
var myNewBox:Box = Pool_myBox.getSprite() as Box;
```

mean that all the proparties and parameters that the class **Box()** has will be given and can be used by the new variable **myNewBox** or it`s a little more tricky that this?

or in other words is **var myNewBox:Box = new Box();**

the same as

**var myNewBox:Box = Pool_myBox.getSprite() as Box;**

------------EDIT-----------

so i do **private var Pool_myBox:SpritePool;** in the Main Class .

and set **Pool_myBox = new SpritePool(Bullet,20);**  so in the 1st moment it has generated 20 objects. 
The whole **SpritePool** class is this

```
package {
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

public class SpritePool {
    private var pool:Array;
    private var counter:int;
    private var classRef:Class;

    public function SpritePool(type:Class, len:int) {
        pool = new Array();
        counter = len;
        classRef = type;

        var i:int = len;
        while (--i > -1) {
            pool[i] = new type();
        }
    }

    public function getSprite():DisplayObject {
        if (counter > 0) {

            return pool[--counter];
        } else {
            increasePool(10);
            return getSprite();
        }
    }

    public function increasePool(amount:int):void {
        counter +=  amount;
         while( --amount > -1 ) 
                pool.unshift ( new classRef() ); 
    }


    public function returnSprite(s:DisplayObject):void {
        pool[counter++] = s;

        //trace(pool.length)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. If your getSprite() method does not return a Box instance (or some descendant of it), it will not 'inherit' the properties of Box. `as` is not performing any kind of internal magic - it is simply casting and telling the compiler that you know what you are doing and that the object indeed is a XXX instance (fill in). You should use casting only when going from a more general type to a more specific type, let's assume this:

```
var child:Sprite = parent.getChildAt(0); //what does this return? A display object instance => compiler will throw an error as Sprite is not DisplayObject
/*
Implicit coercion of a value with static type flash.display:DisplayObject to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:Sprite.
*/
//so you cast it:
var child:Sprite = parent.getChildAt(0) as Sprite; //this won't throw anything cos you casted it correctly
```

Also note that:

```
myObj as MyObj
```

is the same as:

```
MyObj(myObj)
```

Comment: well that gives some light to the problems i have. I guess i have to think a way to "lie" to the compiler . Thanks for the knowledge

Comment: Why do you need to lie to the compiler? There must be a way to achieve this without too much headache, what are you trying to do exactly? Does your pool have objects of different types? Why you can't do it with a single type?

Comment: well it has many types of objects but only 1 that will constantly be generated almost every sec. And i guess ill use the Obj Pool method only for that object (the Box()). Ill edit my post so you can see and if you can give me an advice what to do.

Comment: I can show all the code and show you what im doning if it will help but its a 230lines

Comment: Just to add here - although the two methods of conversion will give the same end result, they will NOT give the same result if the conversion fail. "MyObj(myObj)" will stop the execution of the application and give you an error, while "myObj as MyObj" will simple return null if conversion failed and will not stop the execution.
While it doesn't seem as much of the difference, it's useful to know this - it can save hours of debugging.

Comment: @GeorgeCross Nice, I have never realized that!
user2422650 Can't you simply check with 'is' whether your object is Box?

Comment: well i do **trace (getQualifiedClassName(myNewBox))** and it says it is a Box.I also do http://www.actionscriptdeveloper.co.uk/getting-the-class-of-an-object-in-as3/ and it says its Box too but yet i cant use its properties

Answer (score 0):

if Pool_myBox.getSprite returns only Box objects, then you don't need to cast.  The getSprite function should be look something like:

```
public function getSprite():Box {
    var recycled_box:Box = ...  // get box from pool
    return recycled_box;
}

var myNewBox = Pool_myBox.getSprite();
```

Then, myNewBox will look and act like a Box.  Note that any initialization or processing that happened on previous Box instances must be undone when it's returned to the pool if you need a "fresh" instance of Box.

OK, given the pool class, it looks like it should work with casting.  Note that your text says you're passing in "Bullet" as the Class, while your code seems to want Box's (I assume this is either a typo, or Bullet is a superclass of Box?).  If it works on the first 20, but not after you start recycling, then check what may need to be undone (as above).

What behavior are you seeing that makes you think it's not returning the right Class?

Comment: I made an ---EDIT--- to my post so you can see the whole SpritePool class.So far it is made that it returns any kind of objects